# Append to variable within shell script loop

Tags: shell, sh

I'm trying to loop over all environment variables in a shell script, and create an HTML query string from ones which match a pattern. Unfortunately, I can't seem to assign to variables in the loop. I've got this:

```
#!/bin/sh
IFS=$'\n'
TAGS=""
for item in $(printenv)
do
   if [[ $item == FOO_TAG_* ]]
   then
       TAGS = "${TAGS}&${item}"
   fi
done
```

But this gives me

```
/etc/script.sh: line 9: TAGS: command not found
/etc/script.sh: line 9: TAGS: command not found
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: You cannot use spaces around the `=` in assignments. `TAGS="${TAGS}&${item}"` or `TAGS+="&${item}"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the assignment, remove space between variable name and =

```
TAGS="${TAGS}${item}"
```

Comment: Gah. Why does that matter?

Comment: Otherwise it is understood as invocation of command TAGS with parameters = and "${TAGS}${item}".